# Detecting what is causing uiview animations to be interrupted

Tags: ios

In the animation call:

```
- (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
             animations:(void (^)(void))animations
             completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

There is something that is causing the finished BOOL to become false.  Is there any way to detect that using the debugger?

Comment: whats code written inside this method?

Comment: I thought that was irrelevant because the main problem is finished is set to False

Comment: `finished` will be initially `false` it will be `true` once animation is over.